# Gitlab Yamls does not works properly Job needs

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm facing some issues and would be glad if someone can help me.
My main goal here it's being able to save at the same pipeline, more than one job. The error it’s because the jobs does not exist for the specific branch, since I have 6 branches I don't want to modified one by one. I would like to have only one Yaml version.

When I've tried to save, GitLab show me the following errors.

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:

jobs:deploy_dc_manual:needs:need job should be a string

You can test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint.
```

This, it is a piece of the code. Example if I am in the branch *feature* the job needs it´s "feature_package_build" If I am at integration branch will be expected "int_package_build".

```
feature_package_build:
  extends: .build
  only:
    - /^feature\/.*/
  script:
    # GitLab API query
    - LAST=$(curl -s "sensitive data" | jq '.[0] | .sha' | sed '1q;d' | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:')

    - >
      if [ "$OLDER_COMMIT" == "none" ]; then
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sfpowerkit:project:diff -d package -r ${LAST} -x --loglevel debug
      elif [ "$OLDER_COMMIT" != "none" ]; then
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sfpowerkit:project:diff -d package -r $OLDER_COMMIT -x --loglevel debug
      fi

int_package_build:
  extends: .build
  only:
    - integration  
  script:
    # GitLab API query
    - LAST=$(curl -s "sensitive data" | jq '.[0] | .sha' | sed '1q;d' | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:')

    - >
      if [ "$OLDER_COMMIT" == "none" ]; then
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sfpowerkit:project:diff -d package -r ${LAST} -x --loglevel debug
      elif [ "$OLDER_COMMIT" != "none" ]; then
        node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sfpowerkit:project:diff -d package -r $OLDER_COMMIT -x --loglevel debug
      fi

uat_package_build:
  extends: .build
  only:
    - uat
  script:
    # GitLab API query
    - LAST=$(curl -s "sensitive data" | jq '.[0] | .sha' | sed '1q;d' | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:')

deploy_DC_Manual:
  extends: 
    - .deployDC_Manual
  needs:
    - job:
        if [uat_package_build]; then
        fi
          if [feature_package_build]; then
          fi    
  only:
    - /^feature\/.*/
    - integration 
    - uat
    - release
    - master
  script:
    - nomDeployedDC=${NONDEPLOYEDDC}
    - >

      if [ -f package/destructiveChanges.xml ] && [ "$VALIDATE" == "no" ]; then
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question - and outline what exactly you want - this is alittle bit hard to grasp.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I've added more details. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are looking for is the `optional`-flag for the needs keyword like

```yaml
deploy_DC_Manual:
  extends: 
    - .deployDC_Manual
  needs:
    - job: uat_package_build
      optional: true
    - job: feature_package_build
      optional: true
```

As this makes the needs conditional - but please be aware, that this also means if you mess up your rules, and none of those two is available, your job might be still executed.